# Installation of a Radeon 4870 Graphics card

Tags: mac-pro

I have a Mac Pro Model A1186. I am installing a Radeon 4870 Video Card. Where do I connect the 2 external power jumpers in the MAC Pro?I

Comment: Please could you clarify which Mac Pro you have? `A1186` appears to refer to a few. See http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=A1186

Comment: If it's the 3,1 [Early 08] the connectors are by the front fan assembly, near the top. Cables should already be in situ & just need disentangling. Not sure on the earlier machines.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the 3,1 [Early 08] the connectors are just under the front fan assembly, near the top. Cables should already be in situ & just need disentangling.

Not sure on the earlier machines, but they haven't moved far from there on the 4,1 so it might be reasonably consistent across models

Picture, courtesy of iFixit of the 3,1 location...

[image]